# Is there any APN simulation with different profile for testing?

Tags: android, simulation

My Android app currently has connection problem (can't connect to server) with some APN when the APN protocol is "IPv4/IPv6":

- My app can't connect to my server
- Youtube, Google app still connect to Google server ok

After switching the protocol to "IPv4", every app worked fine.

I need to ask if there is any APN simulation that i can simulate many different APN profile to reproduce the error? (As my users are in a different country so is hard to get real device there).

Comment: Have you checked your server(s) for correct IPv6 support? Because Google usually uses IPv6 and if this works it may be not a client but a server problem. For testing I would first check if your used internet connection is IPv6 capable.